# Is a Measure algebra a sigma algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, boolean-algebra

Given a sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on a set $X$. Let be further given some sigma ideal $I$. Then we can consider $\mathcal{F}/I=\{[A]\mid A\in \mathcal{F}\}$ where $[A]=\{Z:A\triangle Z\in I\}$.
 Is $\mathcal{F}/I$ a sigma algebra on [X]?

Comment: It's for sure an 'abstract' $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. Boolean algebra with countable supremums. To represent abstract Boolean algebras as set algebras, one uses the set of (abstract) *ultrafilters* as base set. Maybe the same (or analogous) representation works for abstract $\sigma$-algebras..

Comment: @Berci thanks for that input. Is there no elementary way to show that this is an sigma algebra, i.e. without the notion of boolean algebra, ultrafilers etc.?

Comment: I can't think of any simpler representation of the abstract $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F/I$. I guess ultrafilters (probably which are closed under countable intersections) will be needed anyway to find a 'base set'.

Comment: You gave the definition of $[A]$ wrong. I fixed that. Also, $[A]%c$ should be the "complement" _in_ the measure algebra, not the complement as a set. That is, $[A]^c$ should be defined to  be  $[A^c]$, not what you wrote.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: $\{A\triangle Z:Z\in I\} =\{B:A\triangle B\in I\}$.

Comment: @Berci I suppose you're right. The definition _should_ be given as in your second version;  an _equivalence class_ should be $[A]=\{B:B\sim A\}$ after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra is an algebraic structure (specifically, a Boolean algebra with a countably infinite operation of countable supremum (satisfying the axiom that it's the supremum of its arguments)), *together with a representation* of its elements as sets, making the operations the real set operations.

When forming the quotient, the 'algebra layer' (the operations and the axioms they satisfy) are kept, but in general, we lose the representation.

However, in some specific cases we can simply determine the new representation, like for example if $I=\{B\in\mathcal F:B\subseteq A\}$ for some $A\in\mathcal F$.

For the general case, we need to generalize the construction of the Boolean algebra case, and for that we need $\sigma$-ultrafilters, i.e. ultrafilters that are closed under countable intersections.

Let $Y:=\{U\ \,\sigma$-ultrafilter on $X: U\cap I=\emptyset\}$, and represent $[A]\in\mathcal F/I$ as $\{U\in Y: A\in U\}$. 
Check that it's a well-defined injective $\sigma$-algebra morphism $\mathcal F/I\to\mathcal P(Y)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra need not have any $\sigma$-ultrafilters. For example, the standard measure algebra (Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo the ideal of measure-zero sets) has no $\sigma$-ultrafilters. So the morphism at the end of your answer won't be injective.

Comment: Hmm.. I was not sure in that part. So, in general it can't be represented?